# Shell - Execute commands in external file between two patterns

Tags: bash, shell

I have got a question. How should I proceed and make this code print out and execute curl examples that I have on my external file?

How I want it to work is to match the pattern, get text between the patterns (without the pattern) and then execute it.

Is there way to do  this?

Thanks for the help.

```
read -p "Enter a word: " instance
testfile=test.txt

case $instance in 
    loresipsum) 
        sed -n '/^loremipsum1/,${p;/^loremipsum2/q}' $testfile \
        |   while read -r line; do
            makingcurlCall=$(eval "$line") 
            echo "makingcurlCall" 
            done < $testfile ;;
         
    foobar)
        sed -n '/^foobar1/,${p;/^foobar2/q}' $testfile \
        |   while read -r line; do
            makingcurlCall=$(eval "$line") 
            echo "makingcurlCall" 
            done < $testfile ;; 
    *)
    printf 'No match for "%s"\n' ":instance" 
esac
```

Text file looks like this

```
loremipsum1

curl example1
curl example2
curl example3


loremipsum2



foobar1

curl foo
curl bar
curl foo

foobar2
```

Comment: Something like `sed -n '/loremipsum1/,/loremipsum2/ p' commands.txt  | grep -v loremipsum | sh`?

Comment: `done < $testfile` means that the while loop is reading directly from `$testfile` and completely ignoring the output of `sed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have the while loop read from both the output of `sed` and directly from the file.  Your current code is ignoring the output from `sed` and reading directly from the file.  Perhaps refactor it like:

```
#!/bin/sh
instance=${1-loresipsum}
testfile=test.txt

case $instance in
loresipsum) sed -n '/^loremipsum1/,/^loremipsum2/p' "$testfile";;
    foobar) sed -n '/^foobar1/,/^foobar2/p' "$testfile";;
         *) echo "Error: no match" >&2;;
esac \
| sed -e 1d -e '$d' -e '/^\s*$/d' | while read -r line; do
#            makingcurlCall=$(eval "$line")
            echo "makingcurlCall: $line"
done
```